# What is an example of a generic shell script that will run correctly in the terminal but not when double-clicked?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, dash-shell

I'd really like to understand the underlying reasons why some scripts work from the command line but not when double-clicked.

Is there an example of a script that does something simple, like echoing a variable or something like that, which would reproducibly work in the command line, but then fail to work when double-clicked?

To be clear, I mean it should run in both instances, but when double-clicked it should fail to perform its task correctly, and it should do this on any recent Ubuntu installation.  I'm hoping that by being able to reproduce the behaviour I can understand it and fix it myself in the future.

Comment: This is an offshoot of this question here:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/872129/this-command-works-in-the-terminal-but-not-in-a-shell-script

That question ultimately wasn't answered, even though the problem I had was solved, so I've marked it as answered because I couldn't keep troubleshooting the script once I solved the underlying problem.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest example:

- create a file "test" and put

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  echo "Hello World!"
  ```

  in it
- make it executable with `chmod 700 test`
- do `./test` on commandline and it will output

  ```
  Hello world!
  ```

From Nautilus:

- default: doubleclick and it will open as a text file
- when set to "run text files" from Nautilus preferences it will flicker a couple of times and then does nothing.

But this is intended behaviour. For Nautilus you would need to create a script that does a "pop up" with the text "Hello world!" in it.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
os.system('zenity --info --text="Hello world!!"')
```

would show ...

[image]

By the way: this also works from command line when you have a desktop. On a tty it would show an error "Failed to connect to Mir".

> and fix it myself in the future

I doubt though there is something to fix. Executing in command line and executing in Nautilus are 2 different things.

Comment: Okay, maybe "echo" was a bad example.  That would obviously fail because there is no command line to show the user the output.  Maybe echoing to a file in a way that fails for the shell script but not for the command line?  The script I had was `LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam` and nobody will tell me why it worked in the command line but failed as a script.  It also worked correctly when run as a script from the command line.  I would like to be able to solve this situation in the future, and I just have no useful information as to how.

Comment: "I doubt though there is something to fix. Executing in command line and executing in Nautilus are 2 different things. " The point is that if I have a script that works from the command line but not from Nautilus, that's a problem I need to solve, and I would like to have the tools to understand how to do that.  I don't want to have to enter the command line to run a script that I might be running everyday, and if the script is run automatically, then doing it from the command line just isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I've got the answer... at least this solves my problem and along the way I stumbled on this and thought I would come back and post an answer.

Shell scripts do not have the same $PATH variable that the terminal does. I can change that for the purpose of the script (in my case using Jupyter notebook as an example) by doing this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh
#this adds the location where jupyter command is found
export PATH="/home/username/anaconda3/bin:$PATH" 
jupyter notebook
```

and that will work.

Additionally some programs may need the terminal to interact with so you could do something like:

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh
#this adds the location where jupyter command is found
export PATH="/home/username/anaconda3/bin:$PATH" 
xterm -e "jupyter notebook" # brings up a terminal window
```

And that will bring up a terminal window to display output and receive input.

Edit: I changed for completeness.